# How to initiate a THROW on a stored procedure if there are 0 results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was wondering what I would have to do to throw an exception on the following stored procedure if there were 0 results so it could select the NULL row? This is for MSSQL, thanks so much.

```
...

BEGIN TRY
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        NoteId,
        Url,
        Subject,
        Content,
        ExpiresAt,
        RemindAt
    FROM dbo.browsingnotes_Notes
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
        AND Hash = @Hash
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        NULL AS 'NoteId',
        NULL AS 'Url',
        NULL AS 'Subject',
        NULL AS 'Content',
        NULL AS 'ExpiresAt',
        NULL AS 'RemindAt'
END CATCH
```

Comment: Is the primary key `UserId, Hash`? If so you don't need two queries for this.

Comment: No, the primary key is NoteId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `RAISERROR` work? Or, as @Candie notes, `THROW` in SQL 2012

You could check `@@RowCount` after the first select, and if 0, select the second.

Comment: Thanks I used:

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
RAISERROR('', 16, 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article

```
THROW [ { error_number | @local_variable },
        { message | @local_variable },
    { state | @local_variable }
] [ ; ]
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee677615.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `UNION` a NULL row on to your resultset if there are not other rows:

```
SELECT
    NoteId, 
    Url, 
    Subject, 
    Content, 
    ExpiresAt, 
    RemindAt 
FROM dbo.browsingnotes_Notes 
WHERE UserId = @UserId 
    AND Hash = @Hash 
union
select NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
  where not exists ( select 42 from dbo.browsingnotes_Notes where UserId = @UserId and Hash = @Hash )
```